# Create MS Access Database in .NET without needing MS Access installed?

Tags: azure, ms-access

We have a client that has a requirement to create exports of data in MS Access databases.  The current plan is to use Azure Platform as a Service which would not allow MS Access installation.  What options are available to export data to MS Access without having MS Access installed on the server using .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Access installed on the server (this assumes your server is some version of windows).  The "database" that "Access" sits on is called Jet and is part of Windows.  Therefore, you could simply copy the database to the server and all would be well.  The only time you need the "Full Blown" installation of Access is when you are using Forms, Reports, Modules, and Macros.

Note, I know nothing about Azure.

All about Jet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine